# Quote Machine cant take new api quote when clicking on button on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have created quoteMachine by ReactJS. Whenever I refresh the page it fire a new quote.But I dont want it to be refreshed, and pulling new quote.I tried to change **random** constant but it didnt work.I also tried to put useeffect inside **changeQuote** function. I think Api fetching doesnt work inside it.
Here is my code

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1643 + 1);
  const [randoms,setRandoms]=useState(random)
  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  const[author,setAuthor]=useState([])

  const changeQuote=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setText(result[randoms].text);
          setAuthor(result[randoms].author)

        },
     
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
  
  return (


    <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center " id="quote-box">
     <h1 id="text">{text}</h1>
     <h4 id="author">{author}</h4>
     <button id="new-quote" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={changeQuote}>New Quote</button>
     <a href=""id="tweet-quote"><i className="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please explain with more clarity what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: @BrunoBraga  I want to create a machine that  show new quote with author on screen. But I couldnt make the button functional for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you are trying to do is to update the quote on every call.

1. There is no reason to make the random constant a state
2. You should be calling the fetch api on every onChange

The code bellow might not compile but you get the idea.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  const[author,setAuthor]=useState([])

  const getQuote = () => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1643 + 1);
    fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setText(result[random].text);
          setAuthor(result[random].author)

        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     getQuote();
  })
  
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center " id="quote-box">
     <h1 id="text">{text}</h1>
     <h4 id="author">{author}</h4>
     <button id="new-quote" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={getQuote}>New Quote</button>
     <a href=""id="tweet-quote"><i className="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: how does useEffect function call the getQuote whenever i refresh it? useEffect used like readyfunction?

Comment: it acts as the old componentDidMount back in the days when react hooks did not exist. So it means it is called everytime the component is mounted